# Setting Ace Editor Cursor Position After Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

**Question:** Is there a way to execute Ace editor commands after the editor has been fully loaded?

I am attempting to set the cursor position of the Ace editor after a page load/re-load. The content of the editor is set in one of the callbacks as the editor is being loaded. Setting the cursor position here doesn't work, since the rest of the editor is still being loaded (like the VirtualRenderer), and it resets the editor content to display from the top.

The code below works, it sets the content, code folds, and cursor position. However, the cursor ends up off the screen, with the content displayed from the top. After the editor fully loads, I would like it to scroll to the cursor.

```
//Put the content of the file into the editor
editor.session.setValue(content);

//Restore code folds
for(var i = 0; i < folds.length; i++) {
  editor.session.addFold("...",folds[i]);
}

//Put the cursor in the correct place
editor.gotoLine(cursor.row,cursor.column, true);
editor.renderer.scrollToRow(cursor.row);
```

Comment: After the editor loads up, try editor.focus(), Its sets focus on your editor and then you can use editor.moveTo() or editor.goToLine() in order to adjust the position of the editor to the required cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
//Put the content of the file into the editor
editor.session.setValue(content);

//Restore code folds
for(var i = 0; i < folds.length; i++) {
  editor.session.addFold("...",folds[i]);
}

//Put the cursor in the correct place
editor.focus();
editor.gotoLine(cursor.row,cursor.column, true);
editor.renderer.scrollToRow(cursor.row);
```

Comment: `cursor` object may be obtained with `editor.selection.getCursor();`